# Set the Default Value for a property in an ADO .NET Data Service

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, entity-framework, ado.net

I have an Entity Data Model being read by an ADO .NET Data Service. 
The entity in question looks like this:

```
**PaidAmount**
Id
FY_1993
FY_1994
...
FY_2030
```

Is it possible to set a default value so that values of 0 aren't serialized?
I have tried setting FY_1993's Default Value to both 0.00 and 0 but when I view the Entity in the .svc the properties still come though as `<d:FY_1993 m:type="Edm.Decimal">0.00</d:FY_1993>` 
Any Ideas?